# how to define a array's length when we do not know the actural size in Java

Tags: java

Question: an unknown number of quiz scores from the stdin and print out the total number of quiz scores, its average, and population standard deviation with 2 decimal places.

My code is :

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex4_2 {

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

  int n = 0;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
  double sum = 0;
  
  int[] scores = new int [n];
     for(int i = 0; i<scores.length; i++)
     {
         scores[i] =input.nextInt();
         sum = sum + scores[i];
     }
     int num = scores.length;
  System.out.printf("Total number of quiz scores = %1.2f \n ", num);
  System.out.printf("Average = %1.2f \n", sum/num);
  
  double total = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<scores.length;i++)
    {
       total += (scores[i]-(sum/num))*(scores[i]-(sum/num));   
    }
    double SD = Math.sqrt(total/num);  
    System.out.printf("Standard deviation = %1.2f \n ",SD);
}
```

}

But when I input 10 20 30, it cannot calculate the right output and there is an error.
I cannot understand the meaning of this error and do not what is mistake.
Please help me... Thank you very much!

Following are the output and errors.

Total number of quiz scores =
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2951)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2898)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1053)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:949)
at Ex4_2.main(Ex4_2.java:16)

Comment: If you don't know the actual size use an `ArrayList`. It can grow dynamically as you add objects.

Comment: Your title says you have a question about array sizes but your question points to an error in printing output. What is your actual question? As for your stacktrace - which line is this error occuring one (it's on line 16, but we can't see what is line 16 for your, so highlight it - and remove all the code that is unnecessary to reproduce the problem)

Answer (score 2):

I assume your real question is 'how do I fix my error?'.

The problem is this line (line 16), as the error message tells you.

```
  System.out.printf("Total number of quiz scores = %1.2f \n ", num);
```

Your error is nothing to do with array sizes.

You are using a format specifier for a floating-point value `%f` with an integer  value `num`.  Use `%d` for an integer. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate the size of the array if you don't know how many items it will hold.  So you need to:

- Initialized it to some arbitrary length, say 10 and set the count to 0.
- Every time you add a value, increment count and compare it to the size of the array.
- if the array is full, copy the contents with a new length using the [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) method in the `Arrays` class.
- when you are done entering in values, you can either leave the array alone or trim it to the number of items using the method mentioned above.

Or better

You can use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--) which does all of the above (and much more) for you.

Comment: And pay attention to overflow situation during capacity expansion if you don't use ```ArrayList```

Comment: @zysaaa bullets two and three already take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

In such case you must try using List. Array list must work in your case.

Please refer :

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-list

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it.
https://replit.com/@TheCodingBros/Java#main.java
First Input no of quiz candidates, then give each candidate marks.
Then it will show u sum total, mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct. Please read and understand.
Additionally,

```
 int n = 0;  
  int[] scores = new int [n];
```

Your loop will always fail because you are instantiating your scores array with 0.
In case if you want a fixed size then for eg. `int[] scores = new int [10];`
Or as per other answer use arraylist for dynamic sizing.